# How do I pass props/data from parent +page.svelte file to a child +page.svelte file in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using the latest version of sveltekit where I'm using the +page.svelte, +page.js, +page.server.js, etc. format. I have a folder called "nowPlaying" that pulls all the movies that are playing in theaters from the movie db. Inside my +page.svelte for this folder I have an object called "pkg" and a function called "acquireMovieInfo" that helps me get movie details on click that looks like this:

```
<script>
  let pkg = {
      movieID: "",
      movieName: "",
      movieOverview: "",
      movieReleaseDate: "",
      moviePosterPath: "",
  }

  function acquireMovieInfo(id, name, overview, release, poster) {
        const userPickID = id;
        const userPickName = name;
        const userPickOverview = overview;
        const userPickReleaseDate = release;
        const userPickPosterPath = poster;
        pkg = {
            movieID: userPickID,
            movieName: userPickName,
            movieOverview: userPickOverview,
            movieReleaseDate: userPickReleaseDate,
            moviePosterPath: userPickPosterPath,
        }
        console.log(pkg);
    }
</script>
```

Under my script I have a ul that lists out all of the movies now playing from my fetch request to the movie db (my fetch request lives in the +page.server.js not shown here) no prob and works great. The list is displayed as the movie posters. My function above is then used like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        {#each movies_nowPlaying as movieNowPlaying}
            <li>
                <a href="/nowPlayingMovieDetails" data-movie-id={movieNowPlaying.id} on:click={() => acquireMovieInfo(movieNowPlaying.id, movieNowPlaying.original_title, movieNowPlaying.overview, movieNowPlaying.release_date, movieNowPlaying.poster_path)}><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{movieNowPlaying.poster_path}" alt="{movieNowPlaying.title} movie poster"></a>
            </li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
</div>
```

All of this works great and per the console log in my function, I am able to get all of the info from each movie poster I click saved to the "pkg" object and able to log it.

My question is how can I now send over the info saved on my pkg to the directory listed on my a tag, nowPlayingMovieDetails, and get this data showing within that +page.svelte that lives in the nowPlayingMovieDetails folder? Because I want my a tag to be clicked and then it lead to the nowPlayingMovieDetails directory where I can then use the data within "pkg" to display the details for that movie that was clicked on.

So far I haven't been able to find how to move this data over especially with the recent update to sveltekit.

My file structure is

```
+ src
  |
  +-- routes
      |
      +-- nowPlaying
          |
          +-- +page.server.js
          +-- +page.svelte
          |
          +-- nowPlayingMovieDetails
              |
              +-- +page.js
              +-- +page.svelte
```

I am fairly new to sveltekit, let alone svelte in general, but I really enjoy using it so if you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Child pages" are not really a thing. You can [compose layouts](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts) hierarchically and insert regular components into pages/layouts but pages are not really children of other pages.

For a scenario like this you usually would use a [path parameter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#using-url-data). I.e. you add a folder in-between using square brackets which captures a parameter: `[id]`.

You then can use that `id` to retrieve the specific item when the page is loaded. You of course have to interpolate the item IDs into the link `href`s.

E.g. you could then create page file path like this:

```
routes/nowPlaying/[id]/details/+page.svelte
```

And create a `href` like this:

```
/nowPlaying/42/details
```

```html
<a href="/nowPlaying/{movieNowPlaying.id}/details" ...>
```